# Azure Pipelines load test

Tags: azure-pipelines, jmeter-plugins, azure-pipelines-yaml, jmeter-maven-plugin

500/javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: i0116 (tried for 8 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

can anyone guide me the step by step reslove this issue

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you've tried to locate a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) with the [id](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) attribute having the value of `i0116` and the element wasn't present in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

I can think of the following reasons:

1. The element ID is dynamic and changes each time you load the page or being auto-generated. In this case you need to amend your [locator](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) accordingly
2. You're using a headless browser which viewport is smaller and the element doesn't fit into the visible area. In this case you might want to [increase browser window size](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#window()), something like

   ```
   WDS.browser.manage().window().maximize()
   ```
3. You can [get the page source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()) and inspect it to see what elements are present in the response

   ```
   WDS.log.info(WDS.browser.getPageSource())
   ```

   and the page HTML source code will be printed to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)